# VBA dynamic link to another file

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have 2 spreadsheets. One of them (Target File) has always same name, and the other one (Source file) has different name.
In Cell A1 of source file I have displayed Source file name.
Each time I save new Source file (with new name) I have to go to VBA and change names, so it points to right file.

```
    Workbooks("Source 05-21.xlsm").Worksheets("Planner").Activate
With Sheets("Planner")
Workbooks.Open ("\\Target File.xlsb"), WriteResPassword:="Hyshndy*hs"
Workbooks("Source File.xlsb").Worksheets("Master").Activate

    Range("A500:E634").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=111
    Range("C716").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks("Source File 05-21.xlsm").Worksheets("Planner").Activate
```

Then copy more data from Source file into target file.

I've tried to use:

```
Filename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planner").Cells(1, 1).Value
Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets("Planner").Activate
```

However as it this is using two different files it is not working.
I would like to be able instead of ***Source 05-21.xlsm*** have link to Cell A1, so I don't have to update code each time the file name changes.

I've tried to look for the solution, however I cannot work it out and my excel/vba knowledge is limited.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Have you checked the value of ``Filename`` to see if it has the right name?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: What is the use of *In Cell A1 of source file I have displayed Source file name.*, or did you mean that one of these 'sources' is the target? Where exactly (*I have to go to VBA and change names*) do you have to change names? In which workbook, worksheet and range? You can copy values as easily as `Range("C716:G850").Value = Range("A500:E634").Value`. But what is the purpose of copying to the same worksheet? You said *I have 2 spreadsheets*, yet there are `Source 05-21.xlsm`, `Source File 05-21.xlsm`, `Source File.xlsb` and `Target File.xlsb`.

Comment: I have template file called Source XX.xlsm where XX is specific period i.e. 05-21 or 06-21 etc the VBA code is in that file. Each period I have to create new file and change code manually, as the file name changed. Filename  option works for another makro, that is copy things to another file. This code finds specific data and then copy set amounts of cells and paste into Target file, and repeats that until all required data is copied. In cell A1 I have formula witch displays current file name including file extension.

Comment: Source File and Source File 05-21 is same file. just my typo when posting this.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of researching and trying different solutions I finally managed to do it.
I used dim option.

```
Dim sLink As String
sLink = Range("A1").Value
Workbooks(sLink).Worksheets("Planner").Activate
```